# Why I am getting NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-roles

I am getting an exception although everything seems to be fine.

> Exception: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[image: error image]

Code breaks at:

```cs
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Input.Role);
```

Code:

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await  _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = CreateUser();
            await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
            await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
            
                if (Input.Role != null) 
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Input.Role);
                }
                else
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Roles.Role_User_Cust);
                }

                var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As usual in these cases, use the debugger and inspect every variable involved in the code that leads to the exception. More info in [What is a NullReferenceException...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it#duplicate=0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Do you have a [mre] available somewhere (like github)?

Comment: are you sure that role that you try to add exists?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You could post the rolelist related code so we can check.

Answer (score 1):

If the exception is thrown at

```
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Input.Role);
```

there are only two objects that can throw a `NullReferenceException`:

- `_userManager`, because the `AddToRoleAsync` method call isn't possible if `_userManager` is `null`.
- `Input`, because the `Role` property access isn't possible if `Input` is `null`.

The stack trace indicates that the exception is thrown deep within `AddToRoleAsync`, so this means that `_userManager` is *not* null. Therefore, `Input` must be null.

In order to address that problem, you'll need to either prevent `Input` from being `null`, or take an alternative course of action if you detect that `Input` is `null`.

Comment: You were right, after debugging I got to know that in Input everything was good except RoleList. RoleList is showing null.
But I still Don't know how to overcome it

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see how the `CreateUser()` works but there's a problem. As `user` is a newly created instance. You should get "user_created" the  from database again to get a full user object.

```
            IdentityUser user_created = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email).Result;                   
            _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user_created, Input.Role);
```

And if Role hasn't been created yet. you need to inject the rolemanager to create a new role.

```
_roleManager.CreateAsync(Input.Role);
```